# How to delete an object from a json in angular 2 and ionic

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

```
export default [
{
  user:{
      id: '1',
      person: 'Theodore Roosevelt',
      text: 'Believe you can and you\'re halfway there',
      icon:'man'
    }
},
{
  user:{
      id: '2',
      person: 'Normale',
      text: 'Change your thoughts and you change your world.',
      icon:'woman'
    }

},    {
  user:{
      id: '3',
      person: 'Thlt',
      text: 'Believe you can and you\'re halfway there',
      icon:'man'
    }
}]
```

The code above is a ts file under data folder in ionic tool.
I wish to delete an entry from this array  on basis of `id` by click of delete button in front of each entry.
I'm new to ionic . I tried .slice it didn't work

Comment: show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
  user:{
      id: '1',
      person: 'Theodore Roosevelt',
      text: 'Believe you can and you\'re halfway there',
      icon:'man'
    }
},
{
  user:{
      id: '2',
      person: 'Normale',
      text: 'Change your thoughts and you change your world.',
      icon:'woman'
    }

},    {
  user:{
      id: '3',
      person: 'Thlt',
      text: 'Believe you can and you\'re halfway there',
      icon:'man'
    }
}]

const id = '2'; // 2 will be removed
const result = arr.filter(item => (item.user || {}).id !== id)
console.log(result)
```